# Avoid Google Chrome login message box?

Tags: google-chrome, login, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any addon or setting how to avoid a "login popup" in the Google chrome? There is an addon which can fill (and sumbit) the login data inside the web page, but I cannot find anything which would automatically confirm the popup dialogue used for https site logins.

I have used such addon for Firefox, called [AutoAuth](http://www.chrisfinke.com/addons/autoauth/), but no luck in Chrome so far.

---

An example of a site displaying a login popup:
[Secure FTP Test Server](ftp://ftp.secureftp-test.com/), courtesy of [Chilkat Software, Inc.](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/). To enter the site use the username **test** and password **test** (see [Welcome to SecureFTP-Test.com](http://www.secureftp-test.com/)).

Comment: Based on this Stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485207/2934514#2934514 I have tried to use AutoLogin script from http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/750, but either it is not working, or I did not install it properly.

Comment: It seems that script does exactly the same as the addons I have tried before, i.e. login within the page, not the https dialogue based login.

Comment: what has https got to do with dialog boxes? What webpages throw a popup to login?

Comment: You can try accessing e.g. https://wiki.bistudio.com (I know you cannot access it, as you do not have account there, but you should still get the https login dialog).

Comment: i'm getting a security certificate not trusted when I visit that site.

Comment: I have edited the question. There is a publicly accessible site test site which anyone can use to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Some Chrome extensions that could help:

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)
[Google Autologin](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fgphecmhejbhcegclnjeedhmhedoggca)
[Auto Login](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oeoibdmcpaofjgcdncagknlmlmngkgfm)

I did the following with Firefox and LastPass :

1. Login to ftp.secureftp-test.com, letting LastPass remember the password
2. Went into the LastPass Vault and clicked Edit of `ftp://ftp.secureftp-test.com/`
3. Put a check-mark in `Auto Login` and OK
4. Set `ftp://ftp.secureftp-test.com/` as my home page

Now whenever I start Firefox, I'm immediately logged-into ftp.secureftp-test.com.

Comment: Unfortunatelly all of them see to do exactly the thing I am not interested about, i.e. login using web form. None of them handles https login dialog.

Comment: @Suma: LastPass does handle https and login dialog - it's a very complete and free product. Did you under-vote?

Comment: I admit I did not try LastPass - it does too much for me. I am not looking for a password manager nor a password online storage, I already have a solution for both of this which I am unwilling to change (basically what is described in http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/11b.html).

Comment: I have tried LastPass now. Still I see no change with the login on the https://wiki.bistudio.com/ site. The login dialog is shown and I have to confirm it.

Comment: LastPass is supposed to give AFTER the login is finished successfully a bar on top of the page with options. Do you get it?

Comment: Not for this particular site. I will check if I will find some other site using the same login method so that anyone can try what I mean.

Comment: Never used it, but the LastPass menu has entry Sites -> Add site.

Comment: When I use Sites, I can login without prompt. This however does not solve why I need it, because I have wiki.bistudio.com as a home page, and in that situation it still gives the prompt (it also gives it when I type the address in the address bar, only not when I navigate through Sites).

Comment: Perhaps it's best to ask the developers thru the LastPass forums at http://forums.lastpass.com/. They do answer, but registration is required.

Comment: @Suma: I added to the answer more info about my experiment with ftp.secureftp-test.com

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work this way for Chrome, at least not for me.

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty, as this is definitely the most helpfull answer (it is the only one anyway). However, as it actually does not solve my issue, I am not marking it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry your issue isn't fully solved. It must be a problem of LastPass under Chrome, so you might go to the forums and try to get it fixed. LastPass is a wonderful tool I couldn't live without, so it's a pity for it to be badly implemented in Chrome.