# How to get Google Chrome to save passwords entered into server generated pop-up login boxes (windows auth)?

Tags: google-chrome, password-management, windows-authentication

Google Chrome does a great job at asking me if I want to save my password on most normal form pages. But if I connect to a server app where the server app asks for Windows authentication it will not ask me if it should save the password. Firefox however does and I'd like to think IE does but I'm not gonna try. Is there a setting to allow for this in Chrome?

Comment: Duplicate of Avoid Google Chrome login message box : http://superuser.com/questions/191841/avoid-google-chrome-login-message-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented in the latest Chrome dev edition, viz, Chrome 7.0.544 dev. Else if you don't want to move to dev channel, try [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)